# Business::ISBN is not validating ISBNs with prefix 9790 in perl

Tags: perl, isbn

Currently, I updated, Business::ISBN and Business::ISBN::Data using

```
cpan Business::ISBN
cpan Business::ISBN::Data
```

but when I tried

```
my $isbn = Business::ISBN->new(9790001012966);
```

so it gave me the following output

```
bless( {
             'type' => 'ISBN13',
             'prefix' => '979',
             'isbn' => '9790001012966',
             'valid' => -2,
             'input_isbn' => '9790001012966',
             'common_data' => '9790001012966'
           }, 'Business::ISBN13' );
```

and when  I did

```
  print Dumper($isbn->is_valid);
```

it just gave a blank string

```
 ''
```

But, when I did the same steps for ISBN with the prefix 978, it gave the correct output

```
bless( {
             'common_data' => '9789087538460',
             'valid' => 1,
             'prefix' => '978',
             'article_code' => '846',
             'type' => 'ISBN13',
             'input_isbn' => '9789087538460',
             'checksum' => '0',
             'isbn' => '9789087538460',
             'publisher_code' => '8753',
             'group_code' => '90'
           }, 'Business::ISBN13' );
```

And even gave positive result when tried to validate it.

```
$isbn->is_valid #result is 1
```

What should I do now to validate ISBNs starting with the prefix 979?

Comment: Seems to be `9790001012966` is not a valid ISBN. Did you checked that?

Comment: It's a valid ISBN and the book corresponding to this ISBN is present in my database.

Comment: As I note in my answer, 979-0 are not ISBNs. Your EAN is not a valid ISBN.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an ISBN. You have an EAN-13. It has the same format as an ISBN-13, but the 979-0 "group" is a special assignment for International Standard Music Numbers and is not a group assigned by the ISBN agency. Hence, it's an invalid *Book* number. Indeed, when you look for the "book" assigned that number, it's sheet music. That catalogs show that number as the "ISBN" data is merely sloppiness on their part.

To deal with these, take off the `9790` to get `001012966`. Add `M` to get `M001012966`. That's your International Standard Music Number, which you can validate with [Business::ISMN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Business::ISMN). But, `Business::ISMN` can do that conversion for you:

```
use Business::ISMN qw(ean_to_ismn);

my $ismn = ean_to_ismn('9790001012966');
```

Comment: Actually, ISBN started prefixing 979 in 2022, it is new.

Comment: And similar case is with 9798886720136, Business::ISBN considers it invalid.

Comment: ISBN has been using 979 much longer than since 2022. Also, they tend to update the ranges and there are instructions in Business::ISBN::Data for using the latest RangeMessage.xml file.

Comment: 979-8 is for English language books, but I'll look into that one.

Comment: So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you read the docs for Business::ISBN::Data?

Comment: If you have problems, you can open an issue at https://github.com/briandfoy/business-isbn-data/issues

Comment: How to set RangeMessage.xml

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a new question. But, the answer is in the Business::ISBN::Data docs.